# Bash Convert text string into array with multiple \r\n as field seperator

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

I have a windows text file in the format:

```
line\r\n
line\r\n
line\r\n
r\n
line\r\n
line\r\n
line\r\n
r\n
...
```

I want to put this textfile into an array where the field seperator is `\r\n\r\n` - I did search for an answer but nothing I found and tried did work . `awk` for example is too complex for me and `FS=` did not work as I expected.

Comment: Do you want to keep `\r\n\r\n` in your text file ? The best way would be to convert your windows file to a Unix format then extract its content to an array with `read` or `awk`

Comment: @Eliot I'm not sure about your actual problem. However, I wrote an awk manual subject about ignoring Windows line-endings: [Modifying rows on-the-fly (e.g. to fix Windows line-endings)](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/awk/3947/row-manipulation/28963/modifying-rows-on-the-fly-e-g-to-fix-windows-line-endings) May be, this helps.

Comment: @Eliot Do you really want to use `\r\n` as field separator? Or is it your line separator? Could you, please, edit your question and provide a small example about what goes in, and what shall come out?

Comment: Yeah, _- - textfile into an array where the field seperator is_ `\r\n\r\n` doesn't make any sense to me. Please elaborate.

Comment: I know how to keep \r\n ;) that's not the problem ;) but even if I have a unix file, I still have 2x \n for field seperator which does not work easily.

Comment: if I would use assembler it would be very easy ;) but the question is not why do you need it... I do need it for some manipulations.  So some help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Eliot in awk you'd just set `RS=""` to tell it to work in paragraph mode and it'd handle the 2x \n (or 2x \r\n) case trivially. Just sayin'... If you post the expected output given that input we could show you how to do whatever you're trying to do the right way. btw if you're considering using a shell loop for this, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) to understand **some** of the reasons not to attempt that.

Answer (score 1):

Commands to read arrays in bash can (as far as I know) only use single characters as a field separator, not complete strings like `\r\n\r\n`.

#### Workaround

- First replace the field separator `\r\n\r\n` with a single char which is not used in the string to be splitted. I found `\x1e`  (the ASCII control character »Record Separator«) to work out quite well.
- Then read the array using the new (one character) field separator.
- The field separator will always be removed when reading something to an array. But you can append the separator to each field.

Here is a pure bash solution to read the file `file` into the array `array`:

```
IFS=$'\x1e'
filecontent="$(< file)"
array=(${filecontent//$'\r\n\r\n'/$'\x1e'})
array=("${array[@]/%/$'\r\n\r\n'}")
```

`IFS=$'\x1e'` sets bash's field separator which is used to split strings into arrays. Depending on your script you may want to restore the old `IFS` afterwards (default is `IFS=$' \t\n'`).

#### Results

For file

```
A B C\r\n
D E F\r\n
\r\n
G H I\r\n
\r\n
```

the resulting array will have two entries:

`${array[0]}`

```
A B C\r\n
D E F\r\n
\r\n
```

`${array[1]}`

```
G H I\r\n
\r\n
```

#### Known Problems

- `IFS` at the beginning and end of the string will be trimmed. Repeated `IFS` will be squeezed. The file `\r\n\r\n` will result in an array without entries. Empty entries cannot be created.
- `\r\n\r\n` is appended to all entries in all cases. The file `A\r\n\r\nB` will result an array with the two entries `A\r\n\r\n` and `B\r\n\r\n`.

Comment: Yes that would be a solution, but is there no way in pure bash? Besides each line is seperated by \r\n... but each element is seperated by \r\n\r\n. So "line\r\nline\r\n\line\r\n\r\n" is one element. And I need to keep the line seperator.

Comment: @Eliot I updated the answer to your needs. For the future: If you have requirements like »pure bash« or »keep separators in fields« please specify them in your question. Regarding your *besides* comment: Even the old answer did this correctly. Did you have any problems?

Comment: @Eliot Glad to hear. Don't forget: you can accept this answer if it was the correct solution. Read more about accepting answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

In Linux all lines of files are terminated with `\n`. 
So your problem is not the `\r\n` , it is just the `\r`. So just remove it:

```
$ tr -d '\r' <file >newfile
```

To verify that `\r` is removed you can do:

```
$ head -n2 newfile |od -t x1c
```

This will get the first two lines of the new file and the od tool will dump / convert those lines in ascii hex codes. In ascii hex `\r` is `\x0d` and `\n` is `\x0a`.

Once you have removed the `\r` from your file you can do anything you want.

You can use all linux tools (including awk) straight forward without special settings.

To built an array you can use:

```
$ while read -r line;do data+=("$line");done <newfile
```

If you want to skip blank lines , this one is enough:

```
$ while read -r line;do [[ "$line" == "" ]] && continue;data+=("$line") ;done <file1
```

You can offcourse combine array creation with removal of the `\r` on-the-fly, without modifying your existed file like this ( [See online testing here.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMV1JKT2tPME9nS2s) )

```
while read -r line;do [[ "$line" == "" ]] && continue;data+=("$line") ;done < <(tr -d '\r' <file1)
```

To see what is inside array "data" just use `$ declare -p data`

PS: By the way using `awk -v RS="\r\n" '{you awk code here}'` should be enough even to read the initial file in awk as well. RS = Record (lines) Separator

Comment: @Eliot updated with "on-the-fly" solution and online testing to play with.

Answer (score 0):

I made this script in pure bash, even if the answer from socowi *is* pure bash too:

```
exec < filern.txt

declare -a array
acc=""
lineno=0
cr=$(echo -en "\r")

while read line; do
  line=${line%$cr}
  if [ -z "$line" ]; then
    let lineno=$lineno+1
    array[$lineno]=$acc
    acc=""
  else
    [ ! -z "$acc" ] && acc="$acc--"      # you can use any separator here
    acc="$acc$line"
  fi
done

echo "Read file in array:"
for ((i=1; i<= ${#array[@]}; i++)) do
  printf "%3.3d  |%s|\n" $i "${array[$i]}"
done
```

It reads a "real" line of input at a time, and strips the trailing \r.
At this point, a sequence \r\n\r\n turns into an empty line, so that is used to assign the array elements one after the other.

The output from the example file is:

> Read file in array:
>   001  |line--line--line|
>   002  |line--line--line|

The separator could also be a \r, or whatever. I coudn't find a way to clear the trailing \r with the command `line=${line% ?? }`, so I used a variable. The same trick can be used to add "strange" separator to the variable ACC. I hope it helps.

Comment: @Eliot FWIW the equivalent awk script to the entire above shell script would be `awk -v RS= -F'\n' -v OFS='--' '{$1=$1; printf "%3.3d |%s|\n", NR, $0}' filern.txt`. You just tell awk that the records are blank-line-separated (`RS=`) and the fields in each input record are newline-separated (`-F'\n'`) and you want the fields separated by 2 dashes on output (`-v OFS='--'`), tell awk to recompile the record using those criteria (`$1=$1`) and then add a `printf` to show the record number (`NR`) and resulting record (`$0`). Something for you to consider when thinking awk is too complex for you!

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, awk is really a pretty tool: powerful, simple, not obscure... I would recommend Eliot to use awk. But... Eliot wants bash probably because he wants to manipulate records, and he (like me) doesn't feel very safe with awk. But it is possible to _decode_ with awk, and do the rest of processing with bash.

Comment: I'm puzzled by `doesn't feel very safe with awk`? Do you think someone is going to hack into your running awk script and steal your data or do you mean something else? If you're going to manipulate records - that's what ask is for which is why it's record-based instead of line-based like sed.

Comment: @EdMorton no no, not safe in that sense. Only in the sense of _comfortable_ (in doing a variety of things in bash, vs a less well known awk). Only that. And mine, is only a supposition.

Comment: Ah, got it. Yes when I first learned UNIX I also muddled by for about 10 years using shell+sed+etc. as I was intimidated by awk, then I forced myself to just spend a day learning it and discovered I'd wasted the previous 10 years on crappy, fragile, inefficient, non-portable hacks :-(. Not saying that's what all shell scripts are but mine for manipulating text were embarrassing!